# Providing a third argument to a priority_queue's compare function

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I've been trying to figure out a way to provide some extra information to my priority queue's compare function. Let's assume I have the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    class IntCompare
    {
        bool operator() (int lhs, int rhs)
        {
            //Do stuff with m_MyMap
        }
    }

    std::map<int, bool> m_MyMap;
    std::priority_queue <int, std::vector<int>, IntCompare> m_MyPriorityQueue;  
};
```

I'd like to be able to access m_MyMap from inside the IntCompare's operator() function. m_MyMap will be modified throughout the lifetime of this object so passing in a copy of this isnt an option. I've tried creating a constructor for IntCompare which takes a pointer, and in the constructor of MyClass, I've tried passing in m_MyMap via the initializer list:

```
IntCompare(std::map<int, bool>* map) : m_MapPointer(map) {} //assuming m_MapPointer is defined in IntCompare.
...
MyClass() : m_MyPriorityQueue(IntCompare(&m_MyMap)) {}
```

but this doesnt seem to work. Was hoping to ask for some help on figuring out if there is a way to do this, or if I need to think of a different approach.

Comment: What does "this doesnt seem to work" mean?

Comment: [You just need to make your `IntCompare` constructor public.](https://godbolt.org/z/9KGKjcedG)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont  Both `MyClass` and `IntCompare` need to have an accessible constructor for `MyClass` to be of any use. The `MyClass` default constructor in  OP's code and my answer is `public`. Yours is `private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way forward: First, make your `IntCompare` constructor and `operator()` public and then ...

Comments inline:

```cpp
class MyClass {
    class IntCompare {
    public:
        // the comparator constructor takes the map as argument and
        // stores a pointer to it:
        IntCompare(std::map<int, bool>& mm) : m_mm(&mm) {}

        bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs) const { // const qualified

            // Do stuff with m_MyMap, via m_mm-> ...
            return lhs < rhs;
        }

    private:
        std::map<int, bool>* m_mm;
    };

public:
    // ...

private:
    std::map<int, bool> m_MyMap;

    // initialize your priority_queue's comparator with m_MyMap:
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, IntCompare>
        m_MyPriorityQueue{m_MyMap};
};
```

Comment: Passing by reference and storing by pointer seems like a bad idea?  I mean, we get a pile of semantic ambiguity.  And other than that, I'm not seeing a difference from what the OP tried and failed.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont _"Passing by reference and storing by pointer seems like a bad idea?"_ - On the contrary, I see it as a good idea. Taking by reference generally signals that a null pointer isn't acceptable. Storing a pointer on the other hand makes copying instances around easy and uncomplicated. The difference between this and what OP tried is that this construct works.

Comment: [In what way does the OP construct not work](https://godbolt.org/z/9KGKjcedG)?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I removed my comment about making the constructor and `operator()` `public` when I deleted it and made an answer - but forgot to mention it in my answer. Added that now.

Comment: 1) `explicit IntCompare(...)`, 2) store a `const` reference/pointer, 3) having a reference member doesn't prevent copyability.

Comment: @Evg I'm not 100% sure what the takeaway is but "3) having a reference member doesn't prevent copyability." is why I **do** prefer a pointer to instance rather than reference. I now  promote my own `non_owning_ptr` to signify relationship. It'll happily point at a proper instance and will be just easy enough.

Comment: I don't understand why you prefer a pointer in this particular case. Today this pointer is initialized from a reference and no not null checks are needed and added. Tomorrow someone refactors this code so that pointer could become null, and code becomes more fragile for no good reason.

Comment: @Evg There's that - but refactoring code that sloppy _should_ trigger some alarm system. Be it human or otherwise. If the possibility to make it a null pointer suddenly becomes necessary, I actually trust the person doing the refactoring to analyze the implications.

Comment: It's not refactoring that would be sloppy, it's code that assumes a pointer to be not null. Between a reference that can't be null by design and abstract trust, I'd prefer a reference.

Comment: @Evg For it to be possible to make the pointer null, and then use it without checking, the class would need some sloppy changes. Having member variables as references makes copy/move semantics unnecessarilly complicated. I want to avoid that.